# how to set background color of ion content

Tags: ionic4, ionic-native

I want to set background color of whole app or a single background color
but what happened if i use div , different device take different height that's why bottom side not cover up and i am unable to set ion content background.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your **app.scss** file :

```
html, body, ion-app, ion-content, ion-page, ion-view, .nav-decor {
    background-color: #yourColor !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bro u can use   in this case i have a stylesheet global with primary color variable

Comment: in this case use <ion-content color="">